# cyclic groups with order which is not prime hint

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm asked the following:

Let $h : C_4 \to Aut(C_{13})$, describe all automorphisms h.

For each homomorphism describe $C_{13} \rtimes_h C_4$

How many distinct isomoprhisms are there in the form $C_{13} \rtimes_h C_4$?

The questions asks to be careful as $4$ is not a prime, however I'm not sure how this helps? I've managed the question without considering whether or not $4$ is prime - could someone tell me why the question said this?

For the homomorphisms I got 4 different cases:

$h(y)(x) = x$

$h(y)(x) = x^5$

$h(y)(x) = x^8$

$h(y)(x) = x^{12}$

as for the groups I received three distinct groups:

1) $C_{13} \times C_4$, $<X,Y|X^{13} = Y^4 = 1, YX = X^5Y>$, $<X,Y|X^{13} = Y^4 = 1, YX = X^8Y>$ where $X = (x,1), Y = (1,y)$

Comment: What were your conclusions about the automorphisms and the groups? Then perhaps we can comment on your work and see whether you have missed something, or whether you successfully navigated the issue here.

Comment: @MarkBennet I have posted my results.

Comment: How do you understand what happens with the last homomorphism? This is the one which has order two - with prime $p$ instead of $4$ you are looking at homomorphisms of order $1$ and $p$. The last one in your list is different.

Comment: @MarkBennet I'm not sure I understand what you mean? I found the homomorphisms by considering the order of each element in $Aut(C_{13})$ and that element has to divide $4$ - those are all the possible homomorphisms.

Comment: But which group does the $x^{12}$ case lead to? You have four homomorphisms and three groups.

Comment: @MarkBennet It leads to a group $<X,Y | X^{13} = Y^4 = 1, YX = X^{12}Y>$ but this is isomorphic to $<X,Y | X^{13} = Y^4 = 1, YX = X^{5}Y>$ which is why I only listed three distinct groups.

Answer (score 0):

$C_4$ has cardinality four. Therefore its image under $h$ must be a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut} C_{13}$ of cardinality $4$, $2$ or $1$.

Comment: I used this - but why does $4$ being prime or not do anything?